# How to skip error and calculate error times in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat, segment

I try to test the statistical power of segmented regression using the [Muggeo(2003)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html) method.

The following is my code to compute structbreak's times. The method is Newton's method whose purpose is to converge to a global maximum, but sometimes it fails and returns an error message. When the structbreak's times equal to zero also returns an error.

```
library(segmented)

breakout <- FALSE ; iteration <- 1 ; max_iter <- 1001
a <- matrix(0 , max_iter , 1)
b <- matrix(0 , max_iter , 1)
c <- matrix(0 , max_iter , 1)

repeat{
  
  TS <- cumsum(rnorm(100,0,1))
  idt <- 1:length(TS)
  o1 <- lm(TS ~ idt)
  os1 <- selgmented(o1, Kmax = 2, type = "bic")
  
  a[iteration] <- ifelse(length(os1$psi[,1]) == 1 , 1 , 0)
  b[iteration] <- ifelse(length(os1$psi[,1]) == 2 , 1 , 0)
  c[iteration] <- ifelse(length(os1$psi[,1]) == 0 , 1 , 0)
  
  iteration <- iteration + 1
  
  if(iteration == max_iter) break }
```

When there is no structure break, the function **selgmented** always return error and loop will be break.

Comment: Have you looked at the `tryCatch` function?

Comment: I have tried the tryCatch function, but I am still understanding its usage.

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with the `segmented` package, but the function name `selgmented()` appears to be a typo. Does the code inside the `repeat` block (a single iteration) actually run as expected?

Comment: The function name is correct, It works as I thought.